# (java)Why is bubblesort not sorting?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm planning on a sorting marathon where I'll look up pseudo-code for common sorting algorithms and try implement them in Java.

The first one I'm trying is bubblesort. I wrote the simplest form which appears to work fine:

```
package bubblesort;

public class Sort {

    private static void swapElements(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        int holder = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = holder;

    }

    public static void ascending(int[] array) {

        boolean sorted = false;
        while(!sorted) {
            sorted = true; //if no elements are swapped, 'sorted' remains equal to true and the while-loop ends.

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
                if(array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                    swapElements(array, i, i + 1);
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

However, since the highest value is brought to the last element each time the for-loop gets executed, I tried to improve it by leaving out elements at the end, introducing a new variable that counts how many times the whole array is checked:

```
package bubblesort;

public class Sort {

    private static void swapElements(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        int holder = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = holder;

    }

    public static void ascending(int[] array) {

        int timesLooped = 0;
        boolean sorted = false;
        while(!sorted) {
            sorted = true;

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length - timesLooped - 1; i++) {
                if(array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                    swapElements(array, i, i + 1);
                    sorted = false;
                }
                timesLooped++;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

This time the sort fails; only some of the elements in the array get sorted, others don't.

So my question is: **What is wrong with the way I introduced the 'timesLooped' variable that attempts to avoid making unnecessary comparisons?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timesLopped++` shall be outside the `for` loop:

```
    public static void ascending(int[] array) {

        int timesLooped = 0;
        boolean sorted = false;
        while(!sorted) {
            sorted = true;

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length - timesLooped - 1; i++) {
                if(array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                    swapElements(array, i, i + 1);
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
            timesLooped++;              
        }
    }
```